# I have a Moto E with a storage problem!

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

Tt the time before installing i had 322 MB free storage and was about to get Dead Trigger 2 but I didn't have enough space so it stopped and now I have only 77 MB free? Did it keep half the app on my phone still?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in **Settings > Storage > Misc**, there should be a temporary file called 'temp' or similar for downloading.

Delete this and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Clean Master works for me, cleans up lots of junk.
CM antivirus as well.

It is also free.

I have no connection with the company, just a satisfied user.